# stop method on hub doesn't fire onDisconnect

Tags: c#, jquery, signalr

When a user logout from my web application, I explicitly end its hub's connection with the following code

```
$.connection.hub.stop();
```

On the server side, I would expect that my implementation of the Hub class would instantly reach my override of OnDisconnected() method wich is not the case. The method ends up by being called but only when the disconnection timeout is reached. What should I do to be notified instantly server side that the stop method was call on my client's hub ?

Comment: is this a single page application?

Comment: Are you sure that's C#?

Comment: @Jonesy No but my hub is instanciated in a global Layout page and so the stop call is.

Comment: My back-end code is in C#

Comment: The reason `OnDisconnected` doesn't fire right away is because SignalR is giving the client a chance to reconnect while the timeout period is elapsing. You can change the timeout period (`GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);`) but I'm not sure you'd want to do that.

Comment: @Cory It makes sense, this would mean I'm probably not closing my connection with the right method. I can't believe that i'm instantly notified on tab or browser close but that I can't do the same by closing my connection manually. What do you think ?

Comment: Actually, after some reading, `stop()` *should* raise the `OnDisconnected` event right away. If it's not, then the connection to the server is not being closed cleanly, i.e., the server is not receiving your `stop()` instruction. How and when are you invoking the line of code in your question?

Comment: Maybe try adding `$.connection.hub.logging = true;` before you `$.connection.hub.start()` to get some additional output from SignalR on the console.

Comment: @Cory OnDisconnected is not fired immediately if client loses phisical connection, computer shuts down or something like that. In that case, server waits for timeout (i think default is 30 secs). But scenario described should work.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a few hours with this. I am using SignalR 2

On a basic script you need to define at least one client callback for events to be raised on the hub..... I eventually found this while [running an example from here.](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/NDCLondon2013/tree/master/UserPresence)

```
chat = $.connection.chatHub;

// Need at least one callback for events to be raised on the hub
chat.client.void = function () { };

$.connection.hub.logging = true;
$.connection.hub.start(); //.done(function () {
```

Now, after all that digging, my breakpoints **finally** get hit on the OWIN C# server.

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
   //logic code removed for brevity
   return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{ 
   //logic code removed for brevity
   return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scenario you've described should work.
If i were you, i would check if your override is correctly done plus i'd check if i have the connection at the moment of calling .stop() on the client.

You might want to do something like this to get some additional info:

```
$.connection.hub.stop()
.done(function(){ console.log('done'); })
.fail(function(){ console.log('Could not stop!'); });
```

});

[SignalR docs about connections management](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#clientdisconnect)

Answer (score 0):

ppumkin, thanks for your answer! 
I've faced same issue, the only difference is that we don't use autoproxies for our hubs.
So, if you create hub proxy in js on your own and expect OnDisconnected event on the hub *without* callbacks tied - add fake event subscription like in this code sample:

```
    export default class MyHubProxy{
        constructor(connection){
            this._myHub = connection.createHubProxy('MyHub');
            this._myHub.on('fake_event', function(){});
        }
    ...
    }
```